# Django: How to get a model class field from other model class?

Tags: django, django-models

I am working on my model classes, trying to get a class field from other class, but I am stuck on this.

Here are the classes:

```
class Cliente(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    endereco = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    telefone = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=10)
    data = models.DateField()

   def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nome
```

I would like to get the "nome" field from the next class:

```
class Pedido(models.Model):

    idcliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente, db_column='idCliente')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return Cliente.objects.get(id=idcliente).nome, Pedido.id
```

This last method **unicode** doesn't get the nome from the Client object.
Also, I would like to get the id(primary key), that is not declared in the model, but the field is actually already created in the table. But I don't know how to get both fields.

Anyone please would help me get this thing to work?
Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

You just have to follow the foreign key field like this:

```
class Pedido(models.Model):

    idcliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente, db_column='idCliente')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.idcliente.nome, self.id
```

The Django ORM will automatically perform a database lookup if required to required to load the appropriate Cliente row.

This will get the `nome` and the `id`.